# set environment variable from inside visual studio code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I like to start Visual Studio Code by opening a particular project with the `GIT_DIR` environment variables set:

```sh
GIT_DIR=~/.local/share/yadm/repo.git code ~/.config/yadm
```

This works, and the git integration reads the `GIT_DIR` variable. However, if I open a second project in a second window of Visual Studio Code, that now also has the `GIT_DIR` set to the same thing, even though I would like it to read that project's git repo.

I want to set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable for only *one* Visual Studio Code project. Is that possible? Can I set it using some command in Visual Studio Code?